# Replacement of fnd_file with utl_file for logging in plsql

Tags: plsql, utl-file, oracle-ebs

My package code contains fnd_file.put_line for logging purpose. I need to replace this with utl_file.put_line what will be the minimum lines of code I should write. there are 100+ occurences of fnd_file.put_line in my code for 14 procedures.
Please explain what is the difference between utl_file and fnd_file?
and give me the sample code as well.

**My question is:**

**Can you please explain if the code is on server then how to give the directory location. It will include the server details as well. Please clarify with the example.**

PS: I can see this package is part of concurrent programming.Is utl_file in scope?

Answer (score 2):

`FND_FILE.PUT_LINE`, will print the string in your output or LOG file, when you run a concurrent program.

```
FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.output, 'message'); -- This will print in Concurrent program output
FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.log, 'message'); -- This will print in Concurrent program log
```

`UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE` is going to print the string in a writable File, which you need to open in your pl-sql.

Example of using UTL_FILE

```
v_chr_out_file       UTL_FILE.file_type;
v_chr_out_file :=
            UTL_FILE.fopen (<directory_path>,
                            <file_name>,
                            'W',
                            32767);
UTL_FILE.put_line (v_chr_out_file, 'this will get written in file');
UTL_FILE.fclose (v_chr_out_file);
```

Comment: what is 32767 in UTL_FILE.fopen (<directory_path>,
                            <file_name>,
                            'W',
                            32767);

Comment: I can see this package is part of concurrent programming.Is utl_file in scope for Logging.

Comment: @Mahi - 32767 is the Max Line size that can be printed in each line. Ofcourse `UTL_FILE` can be used from any PL/SQL package, which is being called by the concurrent program

Comment: Can you please explain if the code is on server then how to give the directory location. It will include the server details as well. Please clarify with the example.

Comment: @Mahi - This is not your original question, also I am not sure, what you are asking

Comment: See for project purpose this code is to go live...so definitely it will be kept on some server...so my question is to how to give the directory location if the file is on some remote server... in local machine I can give like "C:\" for c drive..but if its a remote machine then how to give the utl directory location.

Comment: The directory path needs to be added to `dba_directory` table. This is something only the Database Admins will have access to. `dba_directory` has a field for `directory_name`. you will need to insert one record like `'somepathname', '/path/to/file/'` in the table. then you can use `somepathname` in your UTL_FILE.fopen parameter

Comment: I am getting below error for declare statement----------------- file1 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;               *****error*** >>>                               ERROR line 40, col 10, ending_line 40, ending_col 17, Found 'UTL_FILE', Expecting: ;   -or-   ..  :=  DEFAULT  NOT  NULL   -or-   %   -or-   (  .  @

Comment: how the utl_file will write the logs in some temporary file. we dont have a particular temporary file name. it should generate a temporary file and then write into it.